# How can I write into a variable domain?

Tags: redirect, yii

I have a lot of mirrors (site.com,site.net,site.ru,site.com.ua,ee.site.net,...). All domains are redirected to the main server. How can I write into a variable domain? I use Yii Framework. Urlmanager tried, but I did not succeed. Maybe htaccess?

Comment: They are redirected or they are aliases?

Comment: What do you mean by "write into" a domain? Can you rephrase that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean that all mirrors are redirected to one domain, for example site.com, than the domain information is stored in the referer `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']`. After the first redirection you can store the domain name in the session.